# Http POST/PUT data via LWC or VF

Tags: lightning-web-components, callout

I would like some help in using a LWC or Visualforce page form to populate fields in a wrapper and then eventually post the inputs using a http 'Put' request.

Expected json:

```json
{
      "listingAction": "sale",
      "propertyDetails": {
        "propertyType": [
          "house"
        ],
        "images":[{"resourcetype":"photograph","url":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611622295630-7839220cf0e8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8c2hhY2t8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80"}],
        "bedRooms": 2,
        "bathRooms": 5,
        
        "address": {
          "displayOption": "fullAddress",
          "state": "vic",
          "streetNumber": "27",
          "street": "Nankoor street",
          "suburb": "Bendigo",
          "postcode": "3555"
        },
        "area": {
          "unit": "squareMetres",
          "value": 100
        }
      },
      "contacts": [
        {
          "firstName": "Mike",
          "lastName": "Lastname",
          "phone": "0400000000",
          "email": "test-emails@domain.com.au",
          "receiveEmails": true
        }
      ],
      "domainAgencyID": {{domain.sandbox.agency.id}},
      "providerAdId": "providerId123",
      "description": "New House",
      "summary": "Listing summary here",
      "price": {
        "from": 1000000,
        "to": 1100000
      },
      "auction": {
        "dateTime": "2020-01-28T10:30Z",
        "location": "Onsite"
      },
      "inspectionDetails": {
        "inspections": [
          {
            "from": "2020-01-14T10:30Z",
            "to": "2020-01-14T11:00Z"
          },
          {
            "from": "2020-01-21T10:30Z",
            "to": "2020-01-21T11:00Z"
          }
    ]
```

Wrapper:

```Apex
public class wrapper{
    public String listingAction;    //sale
    public cls_propertyDetails propertyDetails;
    public cls_contacts[] contacts;
    public String providerAdId; //providerId123
    public String DomainAgencyID;   //36111
    public String description = 'DESCRIP';  
    public String summary;  //Listingsummaryhere
    public cls_price price;
    public cls_auction auction;
    public cls_inspectionDetails inspectionDetails;
}
class cls_propertyDetails {
    public cls_propertyType[] propertyType;
    public Integer bedRooms;    //5
    public Integer bathRooms;   //5
    public cls_address address;
    public cls_area area;
}
class cls_propertyType {
    public string house;
    public string apartment;
}
class cls_address {
    public String displayOption;    //fullAddress
    public String state;    //vic
    public String streetNumber; //690
    public String street;   //Nankoorstreet
    public String suburb;   //Bendigo
    public String postcode; //3555
}
class cls_area {
    public String unit; //squareMetres
    public Integer value;   //100
}
class cls_contacts {
    public String domainAgentId;    //234567
    public String domainAgencyId;   //11111
    public String firstName;    //Michael
    public String lastName; //Cuming
    public String phone;    //
    public String fax;  //0282828282
    public String mobile;   //
    public String email;    //mike.Gmail@hotmail.com
    public boolean receiveEmails;
}
class cls_price {
    public Integer from_p;  //1000000
    public Integer to;  //1100000
}
class cls_auction {
    public String dateTime_z;   //2020-01-28T10:30Z
    public String location; //Onsite
}
class cls_inspectionDetails {
    public cls_inspections[] inspections;
}
class cls_inspections {
    public String from_i;   //2020-01-14T10:30Z
    public String to;   //2020-01-14T11:00Z
}
```

callout method /serialize :

```apex
public Pagereference sendPOSTReq(){
            
    Wrapper Property = new Wrapper();
    string ClassJson = JSON.serializePretty(Property);
    system.debug('JSON VERSION IS:'+ClassJson);
     
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('PUT');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
    req.setEndpoint('callout:Domain/v1/listings/residential/');
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = null;
    res = http.send(req);
    req.setBody(ClassJson);
    string body;
    body = res.getBody();
    System.debug(body);
    return null;
```

The callout works fine and the json seems to be set correctly. If I hardcode the values in the Apex, I can pass the values to the 3rd party and they get displayed fine in the correct places.

Now what I'm having trouble figuring out is, how I can create a decent UI to fill out the fields, then - say - click a commandbutton and run sendPOSTReq.

Any help or reference / learning on this would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing new and if your users are using Lightning UI, I would suggest you focus on LWC instead of VF page.

With that said, you can achieve this both in LWC and VF. Approach for Lwc is as follows.

1. Build form in LWC using [Input component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example) and/or other components as appropriate for field data type.
2. Collect all values into various LWC component fields and link them to `onchange` event which should save what user entered into LWC fields
3. Provide a button (for ex., Save) and on click of it, validate the input (for requiredness or correct values) and show errors if there are any.
4. Serialize the Modal you could have created from values after step #3 and send it to Controller method (see below step) as string.
5. Create LWC Controller in Apex which accepts json string and deserialize into your root wrapper class
6. At this time, you have what user entered as Apex wrapper instance which you can send it to `sendPOSTReq`
7. Based on the response from third-party api, returns the status and message back to LWC
8. If successful, show success message and navigate to user next screen. If not, show error in the form and let user correct errors and re-submit.

Since this may be first time you are developing this, I would advice you take one field and take it through end to end. Then keeping adding more fields. So if something fails, you know which field caused this.

Good luck.